# SugarCrm find Opportunities by account name and name

Tags: sugarcrm

I'v done this query to look for opportunities based on account name and name:

```
public function getOpportunity($session_id, $client, $email, $name){

        $acc = $this->getAccount($session_id, $client, $email);
        $acc_id = $acc->entry_list[0]->id;
        $query2 = " 
                            opportunities.id in
                            (select accounts_opportunities.opportunity_id from
                            accounts_opportunities inner join
                            accounts where
                                                    accounts_opportunities.account_id = accounts.id and
                                                    accounts_opportunities.deleted = 0 and
                                                    accounts.deleted = 0 and
                                                    accounts.id = '{$acc_id}')
                            and opportunities.deleted=0
                            and opportunities.name = '{$name}'";

        $op = $client->get_entry_list($session_id, 'Opportunities', $query2);

        return $op;
    }
```

For some reason, it is returning me an error with erro 40 access denied. I don't know why this query is not working. I did a similar one, to find Accounts by email, and it successfully return me the results i want without any error. That query is the following:

```
    public function getAccount($session_id, $client, $email){

        $query = "accounts.id in 
( select bean_id from 
email_addr_bean_rel inner join
email_addresses where 
email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id = email_addresses.id 
and email_addr_bean_rel.deleted = 0 and
email_addresses.deleted = 0 and 
bean_module = 'Accounts' and
email_addresses.email_address = '{$email}' )";

        $acc = $client->get_entry_list($session_id, 'Accounts', $query);
        return $acc;   
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDITED: I'm using SOAP API and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this blog post for more details...

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/03/19/howto-avoiding-subqueries-with-our-web-services/